# Make these slides loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on this for a little while, and I think I'm stuck at this point.

I made a div slider with arrows. Each div slide is set to a *min-width* of *80px*.

The code works just fine, except, when I navigate either to the left or the right, it stops at the last item. I want this slider to loop (as in endlessly), instead of ending at the last item.

```js
let buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slide_left')
    let buttonRight = document.getElementById('slide_right')

    buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft -= 90
    })

    buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft += 90
    })
```

```css
body{
            background-color: #555;
            height: 100vh;
            display: grid;
            align-items: center;
            justify-items: center;
            font-family: 'Helvetica';
        }
        
        div#slide_wrapper{
            width: 440px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            height: fit-content;
        }
        
        div#slider{
            width: 350px;
            display: flex;
            height: fit-content;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        div.thumbnail{
            min-width: 80px;
            min-height: 80px;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: grid;
            place-items: center;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        div.thumbnail:not(:last-child){
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        div.thumbnail:nth-child(1){
            background-color: darkturquoise;
        }
        div.thumbnail:nth-child(2){
            background-color: goldenrod;
        }
        div.thumbnail:nth-child(3){
            background-color: rebeccapurple;
        }
        div.thumbnail:nth-child(4){
            background-color: powderblue;
        }
        div.thumbnail:nth-child(5){
            background-color: firebrick;
        }
        div.thumbnail:nth-child(6){
            background-color: sienna;
        }
        div.thumbnail:nth-child(7){
            background-color: bisque;
        }
        div.thumbnail:nth-child(8){
            background-color: navy;
        }
        
        div#slide_wrapper > button{
            height: fit-content;
            align-self: center;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: 800;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
        }
        
        div#slide_wrapper > button:hover{
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: dodgerblue;
            color: #fff;
        }
```

```html
<div id="slide_wrapper">
        <button id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow">&#10094;</button>
        <div id="slider">
            <div class="thumbnail active">1</div>
            <div class="thumbnail">2</div>
            <div class="thumbnail">3</div>
            <div class="thumbnail">4</div>
            <div class="thumbnail">5</div>
            <div class="thumbnail">6</div>
            <div class="thumbnail">7</div>
            <div class="thumbnail">8</div>
        </div>
        <button id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow">&#10095;</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice slider! There are several ways to achieve what you want. In my opinion, the simplest solution would be to work with some if conditions and a counter variable. Once the number of thumbnails is reached, set the counter back to 0.

#### Update

Regarding to your comment. *"How about doing the same for the left arrow."*. In the if condition block: `if (0 == slideCount) {` i add these lines:

```js
    slideCount = thumbnail.length // set the slideCounter to maximum
    document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft = slideCount * 90 // calculate the scroll distance
    slideCount--; // decrease slidecount
    setActive();  // set the red border on the current slide
```

```js
const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slide_left')
const  buttonRight = document.getElementById('slide_right')
const thumbnail = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");
let slideCount = 0;
setActive();

buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (0 == slideCount) {
    slideCount = thumbnail.length
    document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft = slideCount * 90
    slideCount--;
    setActive();    
    return;
  }
  slideCount--;
  document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft -= 90  
  setActive();
})

buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  slideCount++;
  if ( 8  ==  slideCount) {    
    document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft = 0
    slideCount = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft += 90  
  }    
  setActive();
})

function setActive() {  
  thumbnail.forEach(t => {
    t.classList.remove("active");
  })
  thumbnail[slideCount].classList.add("active")
}


function count() {
  console.log(slideCount);
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

div#slide_wrapper{
  width: 440px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: fit-content;
}

div#slider{
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.thumbnail{
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.thumbnail:not(:last-child){
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(1){
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}
div.thumbnail:nth-child(2){
  background-color: goldenrod;
}
div.thumbnail:nth-child(3){
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
div.thumbnail:nth-child(4){
  background-color: powderblue;
}
div.thumbnail:nth-child(5){
  background-color: firebrick;
}
div.thumbnail:nth-child(6){
  background-color: sienna;
}
div.thumbnail:nth-child(7){
  background-color: bisque;
}
div.thumbnail:nth-child(8){
  background-color: navy;
}

div#slide_wrapper > button{
  height: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

div#slide_wrapper > button:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: #fff;
}

.active {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide_wrapper">
  <button id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow">&#10094;</button>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="thumbnail active">1</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">2</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">3</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">4</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">5</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">6</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">7</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">8</div>
  </div>
  <button id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How about doing the same for the left arrow. It only seems to work for the right arrow. All the same for the tremendous effort.

Comment: @MattDon You welcome! I updated my answer. Your question is about the effect to the right. Therefore, I assumed that this is what you wanted. But to implement this effect of "jumping" here too, you only have to insert a few lines of logic in the if-condition. I commented on what happens in my answer.

Comment: @MattDon If you find that my answer was helpful it would be nice if you accept my answer. If you like it you can answers upvote. Thank you ;-)

Comment: You are a genius. I will say it again. YOU ARE A GENIUS! Thank You.

Comment: @MattDon I am not a "genius" :-) but thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Oh, one more thing (sorry to be a burden). Do you notice how it sort of "jumps" to the next sequence instead of following the usual order? What I'm saying is after reaching 8, the next number to show should be 1, followed by 2, 3, and so on. Also, when at number 1, the next number to show should be 8, followed by 7, 6, and so on.

Comment: Please, help me out Mr. Lowrey. I know you can solve this. All the same, a big thank you for your ingenious aid.

Comment: @MattDon I don't really know what you mean. Can you please try to explain it again?!  Currently it is like this: `-> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,...` and `<- 1,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245587/discussion-between-matt-don-and-maik-lowrey).

Answer (score 0):

Just find the width of the slider and compare it with the scroll left like

```
 let buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slide_left')
let buttonRight = document.getElementById('slide_right')

buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft -= 90
})

buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {

  const elem = document.getElementById('slider');
  
  const ElemWidth = elem.getClientRects()[0].width
 
  
   
  
 if(document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft > ElemWidth ){
    document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft = 0
 }else{
   document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft += 90 
 }
  
   console.log(ElemWidth,  document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft , document.getElementById('slider').scrollLeft > ElemWidth)
})
```

Comment: Mr. Faizal sir, could you try this JS solution in my code? I tried it. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: please view this working code 
https://jsbin.com/nacimefiqu/edit?html,css,js,console,output

I

Comment: ive edited my code a bit

Comment: It works just fine. How about doing the same functionality for the left arrow? Just the way it is for the right.